# 2d array created with wrong dimensions

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm quite new to Java and I've got the following problem:

```
private static int[][] Resize(int[][] arr)
{

    int[][] arr2 = new int[arr[0].length-2][arr[1].length-2];
}
```

I'm trying to create a new 2D array in the function that's smaller than the original by two.

In this example(checked through debugging):

```
arr[0].length = 3
arr[1].length = 3
```

So I want arr2 to be a 1x1 array, but it seems that I'm getting an outofbounds exception on the second dimension.

I can print/use `arr2[0].length`, but whenever I try to use `arr2[1].length` I keep getting an outofbounds exception.

I can't use `arr2[0].length` for both dimensions, are the dimensions won't always be the same.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `arr2[1]` gets the **second** element of `arr2` - but that doesn't exist.

Comment: You've written `arr2[1]` instead of `arr2[0][0]`. My guess is that `arr[1]` should be `arr[0][0]` as well.

Comment: First, checking the row length is arr2.length, and column by arr2[0].length. Secondly, 1x1 array is a one dimensional array.

Comment: @tiborK ohh I thought arr[0] was the row ans arr[1] the column, thanks for the help!

Comment: @JuanCoret my pleasure

Comment: It's not a one-dimensional array as it's still defined as a two-dimensional one. If you're going that route you should instead define it as a zero-dimensional array as it can only hold one value (i.e. might as well just be an `int`).

Comment: @Gendarme yes, the arrays could have any size nxm, including 1x1, I just used 3x3 ->1x1 for the example( not the best example I guess)

Comment: `int[][] arr2 = new int[arr.length-2][arr[0].length-2];`